# Integrals of the form $(\sin^n(x)\cos^m(x))dx$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

To solve the integrals of the form $(\sin^n(x)\cos^m(x))$, my book uses the sum of $m$ and $n$ to make appropriate substitution.

Eg:

$$\int \sec^3(x)\csc(x) \, dx$$

Sol:

sum of powers=$-4$ {even and negative}, co substitute $t=\tan(x)$

And the rest just becomes easy.

How did they decide to substitute $\tan x$? What is the intuition behind this?

Comment: A general method for trigonometric integrals is the use of [Bioche's rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioche%27s_rules).

Comment: Thanks! The reference was really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Working Rule:

1.) If one of them is odd , then substitute for the term of even Power .

2.) if both are odd, substitute either of them .

3.) if both are even , use trigonometric identities only.

4.) if m and n are rational numbers and m+n-2/2 is a negative integer , then substitute cot X=P or tan X=P whichever is found suitable.

Answer (score 0):

As we know that integrations of certain functions cannot be obtained directly if they are not in the standard form, but they may be reduced to standard forms by proper substitution.

Here, the integral is such that we cannot directly make a substitution rather it requires further more simplification in order to substitute any function. If the integral was such that $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ then we would have substituted either $t=\sin x$ or $\cos x$ depending upon $m$ or $n$ is odd. See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRe0w.jpg) illustration.

But if $m, n \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $m+n\in \mathbb{Z^-}$, we need to find another substitution and so we move on to $\tan x$-$\sec^2x$ pair. In order to change the integrand in terms of $\tan x$ and $\sec^2x$, we've to divide numerator and denominator by $\cos^kx$, where $k=-(m+n) $ and then substitute $\tan x=t$. See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZ0Is.jpg)* illustration.

In the first illustration it is clear that substituting $\tan x=t$ is of no use as $\sec^2x$ is not generated in the numerator efficiently by doing so. The substitution which we're making should be relevant and it should make the integrand more simplified rather than complicating it. That's why in the second case it is preferred the substitution of $\tan x=t$ over $\sin$ or $\cos$.

---

*Typo in the image. It should be "[Dividing $N^r$ and $D^r$ by $\cos^4 x$]".

Comment: Can you please emphasize more on why it is plausible to substitute sinx and cosx based on whether m and n are even or odd? And why tanx when their sum is negative?

Comment: Ok, I'll edit it in the answer.

Comment: @DatBoi, I've edited the solution. If there's still any confusion, notify me.